# How to set up intel SDK to android 4.4?

Tags: cordova, intel-xdk

I need the SDK to be 4.4 so I can use crosswalk with kitkat (since my application is using sockets)

[image]

Device is set now to 4.2. I have no idea how to set it up to 4.4

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build with Crosswalk, choose the Crosswalk for Android build tile under the Cordova Hybrid built options. To not use the Legacy build tiles. Crosswalk replaces the webview, so you can use web sockets on Android 4.0+ devices and are not limited to using just Android 4.4+ devices.

We recommend using Crosswalk whenever you can, because it provides this enhanced webview on Android and makes life much easier. At this time, the best Crosswalk version to specify, in the build settings, is Crosswalk 10.

On the "BUILD" tab:

[image: crosswalk-for-android-build-tile]

On the "PROJECTS" tab with the "Crosswalk for Android" section of the "Build Settings" selected:

[image: crosswalk-version]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot about where to "choose the Crosswalk for Android build tile under the Cordova Hybrid built options"

Comment: I did that already. However my crosswalk website does not work with sockets !
My website www.fox-poker.com uses sockets. My crosswalk project is SIMPLY a windows.navigate("http://www.fox-poker"); 1 line code. But the socket part of the site just stucks whereas fox-poker.com works fine on my mobile. 

Any idea ?

Comment: When you execute that windows.navigate() you are probably running into either a CORS issue (which you can address using the "whitelist" feature in the Crosswalk build settings on the Projects tab) or your page is getting opened in something other than the Crosswalk runtime and the web sockets feature is missing. I recommend you use the inAppBrowser to open that page within Crosswalk and use the options that insure you stay within the embedded webview. See docs here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser